# Using foreach in PHP with JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
{
    "set_id": "10001",
    "name": "4x4 car",
    "img_url": "https://xxx.xxx.com/img/sets-b/10001.jpg",
    "parts": [
        {
            "part_id": "1001",
            "qty": "2",
            "color_id": "0",
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "part_id": "1002",
            "qty": "2",
            "color_id": "0",
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "part_id": "1003",
            "qty": "2",
            "color_id": "0",
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "part_id": "1004",
            "qty": "2",
            "color_id": "0",
            "type": 1
        }
    ]
}
    ]
```

I am using PHP code like this:

```
 while($item = array_shift($json_output))
 {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key.' => '.$value."\n";
    }
 }
```

But it returns the result:

```
set_id => 9398-1 descr => 4 x 4 Crawler set_img_url => https://img.rebrickable.com/img/sets-b/9398-1.jpg parts => Array
```

How do I want to return the `parts` info?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the parts

```
foreach ($item{"parts"] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key.' => '.$value."\n";
}
```

Sample here: [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ab9a0592ca9a8f735fdc326c82ced39755ad16c)
If you want every 2 level property:

```
$items=json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($items as  $item) {

    foreach ($item as $key => $value)
    {
       if( is_array($value) ) { 

          foreach ($value as $subkey => $part)
          {
              foreach ($part as $partkey => $partvalue)
              {
                  echo $key .' '. $subkey . ' ['.$partkey.'] => '.$partvalue."\n";
              }
          }
       } else {

        echo $key.' => '.$value."\n";
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for you help,but now it's return only the array like this,=> Array parts[150] => Array parts[151] => Array parts[152] => Array parts[153] => Array parts[154] => Array parts[155] => Array parts[156] => Array parts[157] => Array parts[158] => Array parts[159] => Array parts[160] => Array parts[161] => Array parts[162] => Array parts[163] => Array parts[164] => Array parts[165] => Array parts[166] => Array parts[167] => Array parts[168] => Array,what should i do?

Comment: thanks a lot，and I need you help,I also want to get each value of $partvalue[part_id] [part_name] 's value to display in html,i use $part_id = $partvalue[part_id],but it's return the incorect data,thx

Comment: there is no `part_name` in your json, what do you mean?

Comment: i want get the part_id,part_name,etc value，echo them to display     echo $partvalue['part_id'].'<br>'; it's return 4
2
0

P
B
h
4
h


3
2
0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `$array_json = json_decode($json_var, true)` and then `$parts = $array_json["parts"];` (I haven't execute the code, maybe has some errors)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php